# Is this homomorphic property about orthogonality $a' \cdot\psi(b) =\psi(c)\to (\exists a.\ a' = \psi(a)\land a \cdot b = c)?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, definition, group-homomorphism

I'm studying a special sort of homomorphisms between partial group-like structures, of the property below,
$$\forall a' b c.\ \ a' \cdot \psi(b) = \psi(c) \to (\exists a.\ \ a' = \psi(a) \land a \cdot b = c)$$

Does this property has a known name? Thank you.

---

This is a property abstracted from separation algebra, and I find I'm using it everywere in my work so I feel there should be a name or some existing research for it.
Bellow is my breif interpretaion about the property (can be misleading!):

It first gives me a sense of 'embedding'. For $\psi: A \rightarrow B$, the $A$ is embedded in a larger $B$. If $\psi(b)$ combined with some $a'$ still falls in $A$, then $a'$ must be some element in $A$ without any 'noise' from outside. It sounds like, elements from outside cannot make elements in $A$ by applying with elements in $A$. In my work, I use $B$ like a big container (a finite product), and inject several such $A$ into it. By this property, I can recover an injected element back.

Maybe another similar (but weaker) form can be more intuitive,
$$\forall a\,a'\,b' c'.\ \ a' \cdot b' = c' \land a' = \psi(a) \land (\not\exists b.\ b' = \psi(b)) \to (\not \exists c.\ c' = \psi(c))$$
If the image $a' = \psi(a)$ is applied with another element that is not an image of $A$, the result will not fall in the image of $A$. It shows the homomorphism has some 'orthogonal' sense. $b'$ brings some elements not belonging to $A$, the application of $a' \cdot b'$ still contains those external elements so it cannot fall in the image of $A$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041); for example, use `$\forall$` for $\forall$ :)

Comment: I can't quite make this precise but this strongly resembles the categorical concept of creating and reflecting (co)limits and (co)cones

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I find an answer but not sure, so please correct me if I am wrong.

It is an orthogonality between the group actions and the homomorphism.

---

First, we consider total monoid, and construct a category
embedding the monoids and the homomorphism. It consists of two objects $A,B$ which are carrier sets of monoids $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, and their endomorphisms are the group actions of the monoids respectively. The only arrow from $A$ to $B$ is the homomorphism $\psi$.

[image]

The property $a' \cdot \psi(b) = \psi(c) \longrightarrow (\exists a.\ a' = \psi(a) \land a \cdot b = c)$ is characterized by the following commute diagram (ignore the red arrow for now). We use bold-face $\mathbf{a}(x) \triangleq a \cdot x$ to differentiate a left group action and the group element.

[image]

The existence of group element $a$ implies the existence of an arrow $\mathbf{a}$ that commutes.

The red arrow denotes $\mathbf{a}' \circ \psi$. We rearrange $\mathbf{b}, \mathbf{a}, \psi$ and the red arrow,

[image]

then we get the standard diagram for [orthogonality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/orthogonality).

If the property $a' \cdot \psi(b) = \psi(c) \longrightarrow (\exists a.\ a' = \psi(a) \land a \cdot b = c)$ is held, the arrow $\mathbf{a}$ exists and commutes in each triangles (note $\psi \circ \mathbf{a} = \lambda x. \psi(a \cdot x) = \mathbf{a}' \circ \psi$).
According to the definition of orthogonality, $\mathbf{b} \perp \psi$, the group action of $b$ is orthogonal to the homomorphism $\psi$.

Reversely, it is also true. From the existence of $\mathbf{a}$, we can show the corresponding $a$ is the witness of the existence in the property. So the orthogonality also implies the property.

---

The conclusion can be extended to partial monoids if we change the way to construct the category (I am not sure if there is a standard approach embedding partial algebras into categories).

The objects are the elements of the two algebras, the morphisms are still group actions. There is an arrow $\mathbf{a}$ from $b$ to $c$ iff $a \cdot b = c$. Between the objects of $\mathcal{A}$'s elements and that of $\mathcal{B}$, there is an arrow $\psi$ from $a$ to $a'$ iff $a' = \psi(a)$. By this setting, the conclusion should be extended.

To handle non-unital and non-associative algberas, we only need to add a special initial object from which morphisms are constant functions returning the group elements, and let the two left-most objects in the second diagram be the initial object.